# Flipswitch packaging error... Theos

Tags: ios, makefile, package, cydia, theos

I'm trying to make a Flipswitch package for my Cydia tweak. I have all headers in their appropriate directories, as well as, the Makefile edited.

My problem is that I keep getting a:

```
ld: library not found for -lflipswitch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

error!?!?

I have researched the devwiki, Ryan Petrich examples and a3tweaks examples.  Regardless of what example (even the basic template), I keep getting the error.  Any ideas?

TIA

Here's the full process during 'make package.' My test Flipswitch is called 'stop test.'

```
/Users/appleimac/Documents/stoptest/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:49: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for bundle stoptest...
 Copying resource directories into the bundle wrapper...
 Linking bundle stoptest (armv7)...
ld: library not found for -lflipswitch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/stoptest.bundle/stoptest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/stoptest.bundle/stoptest] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-bundle-all_] Error 2
make: *** [stoptest.all.bundle.variables] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the library. See [this section of the devwiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Flipswitch#How_to_use_this_library) to fix this.

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you so much! I thought that was referring to what would be created on an iDevice once Flipswitch was installed so I ignored it. LOL!  Kind of think there should be a link to it in the devwiki instead of us having to manually place it on our computer.